# Why subplots are not taking all space allowed by figure in Matplotlib embedded with Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, subplot

I want to show a lot of subplots in a Tkinter window and be able to scrolldown to see all the plots with a good size. However, it is all packed and it seems that the subplots don't take all the space allowed in my figure and only restricts to the space of the window. How can I make it more spaced out and make the subplots bigger?

I've tried different paddings with the `tight_layout()` option, changing the figure size and other parameters of Tkinter like the `fill` or `expand` in my widgets.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Scrollbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class ScrollableWindow:

    def __init__(self, master, fig, **options):

        master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (800, 500))
        master.focus_set()

        fig_wrapper = tk.Frame(master, width=800, height=fig.get_figheight())
        fig_wrapper.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        fig_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=fig_wrapper)

        scrollbar = Scrollbar(fig_wrapper, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)
        fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set, scrollregion=fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().bbox("all"), width=800, height=1000)



n_col, n_row = 3, 11

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(n_col,n_row*2), ncols=n_col, nrows=n_row)
for i in range(axes.shape[0]):
    for j in range(axes.shape[1]):
        axes[i,j].set_xlabel("xlabel")
        axes[i,j].set_ylabel("ylabel")
fig.tight_layout()
showStatsWindow = tk.Tk()
showStatsWindow_ = ScrollableWindow(showStatsWindow, fig)
showStatsWindow.mainloop()
```

Here's an example with empty plots of what it looks like. I want to have 3 or 4 subplots per row, but it is all squeezed together. As you can see, I have more space down in my window and it changes with the figsize parameter but it's all blank.

[image]

Comment: fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.10, right=0.96, left= 0.08, top=0.95,wspace=0.10)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. The plots still don't take all the space in my figure.

Comment: The problem is foremost that the figure does not obey to its initial dimensions but is resized inside the tk widget. Once you have solved that problem, you can call tight_layout within the figure of desired size.

Comment: your problem is the scroll bar chekout how to set the scrollbar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526496/vertical-scrollbar-for-frame-in-tkinter-python)

Answer (score 3):

Let me first start with the **size** of `tkinter-Window` which is showing matplotlib figure e.g `subplots`. Actually, it the fixed window size `master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (800, 500))` which is bothering you.

When you simply use tkinter window, It will `automatically` resize itself to the figure size. And inversely, if it is resized, the figure will resize as well. There is simple workaround for the above mentioned problem.

> - Replace the following line :
>
>   ```
>   master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (800, 500))
>   ```
> - with:
>
>   ```
>   master.resizable(width=False, height=False)
>   ```

To provent tkinter window from being resized .
Now to make your size of subplots bigger or smaller, you can change it by changing the `figsize=()` parameter accordingly.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=n_col, nrows=n_row, figsize=(7.5, 25))
```

I'll must refer you to use `PyQT5`, which is more feasible in your given scenario. A working **example** is given below, where instead of calling `tkinter` custom operations such as `pack()` and `config()` etc.

`Qt5` puts the figure into a canvas with scrollbars, such that the figure retains it's original size and can be scrolled within the Qt window. You wouldn't have to deal with the details inside the class but only the call at the end of the script.

Visit reference: [Developing GUIs in Python: Tkinter vs PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094155/developing-guis-in-python-tkinter-vs-pyqt).

```
import matplotlib
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')


class ScrollableWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, fig):

        self.q_app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        #  To set this size of the Display Window
        self.setFixedSize(800, 500)

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.widget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        self.widget.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.widget.layout().setSpacing(10)

        self.fig = fig
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.canvas)

        self.nav = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.widget)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.nav)
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.scroll)

        self.show()
        exit(self.q_app.exec_())


fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=11, figsize=(7.5, 25))

for i in range(axes.shape[0]):
    for j in range(axes.shape[1]):
        axes[i, j].set_xlabel("x-label")
        axes[i, j].set_ylabel("y-label")


fig.tight_layout()
ScrollableWindow(fig)
```

Here is a result using `PyQT5`:

[image: Simple Result with PyQT5]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply! This seems to nicely fix the whitespace around the figures, but not the scrolling problem where the figures. stay squished into one view, and the scrollbar scrolls down into blank space.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that your scrollbar wasn't set the correct way if you want to see how to set it correctly ckeckout this [Vertical scrollbar for frame in Tkinter, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526496/vertical-scrollbar-for-frame-in-tkinter-python) and [How to get frame in canvas window to expand to the size of the canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319445/tkinter-how-to-get-frame-in-canvas-window-to-expand-to-the-size-of-the-canvas)

The frame where you drawing your figure wasn't expanding ....

here is how I fixed it

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Scrollbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ScrollableWindow:

    def __init__(self, master, fig, **options):
        def on_configure(event):
            # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
            # when all widgets are in canvas
            canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))

            # expand canvas_frame when canvas changes its size
            canvas_width = event.width
            canvas.itemconfig(canvas_frame, width=canvas_width)


        # --- create canvas with scrollbar ---
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master, )
        canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill='both', expand=True)

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master, command=canvas.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='both')

        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
        # when all widgets are in canvas
        canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)

        # --- put frame in canvas ---

        fig_wrapper = tk.Frame(canvas)

        canvas_frame= canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=fig_wrapper,)

        master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (800, 500))
        master.focus_set()

        fig_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=fig_wrapper)
        fig_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, side=tk.LEFT, expand=True)


n_col, n_row = 3, 11

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(n_col*2,n_row*2), ncols=n_col, nrows=n_row,)
for i in range(axes.shape[0]):
    for j in range(axes.shape[1]):
        axes[i,j].set_xlabel("xlabel")
        axes[i,j].set_ylabel("ylabel")
fig.tight_layout()
showStatsWindow = tk.Tk()
showStatsWindow_ = ScrollableWindow(showStatsWindow, fig)
showStatsWindow.mainloop()
```

here is the result I got

[image]

Answer (score 0):

more optional customization if you need call this function by tkinter grid.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Scrollbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg


class ScrollableTkAggY(FigureCanvasTkAgg):
    def __init__(self, figure, master, *args, **kwargs):
        # --- create canvas with scrollbar ---
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.fig_wrapper = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.fig_wrapper.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.fig_wrapper.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.fig_wrapper.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        super(ScrollableTkAggY, self).__init__(figure, master=self.fig_wrapper, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tkagg = self.get_tk_widget()
        self.tkagg.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        self.vbar = Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.NS)

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vbar.set, scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

        # when all widgets are in canvas
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)
        # --- put frame in canvas ---
        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.fig_wrapper, anchor=tk.NW)

        ScrollableTkAggY_meths = vars(ScrollableTkAggY).keys()
        methods = vars(Pack).keys() | vars(Grid).keys() | vars(Place).keys()
        methods = methods.difference(ScrollableTkAggY_meths)

        for m in methods:
            if m[0] != '_' and m != 'config' and m != 'configure':
                setattr(self, m, getattr(self.canvas, m))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.canvas)

    # expand canvas_frame when canvas changes its size
    def on_configure(self, event):
        # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'

        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))
        # when all widgets are in canvas
        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_frame, width=canvas_width - 20)


class ScrollableTkAggX(FigureCanvasTkAgg):
    def __init__(self, figure, master, *args, **kwargs):
        # --- create canvas with scrollbar ---
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(master)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.fig_wrapper = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.fig_wrapper.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
        self.fig_wrapper.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.fig_wrapper.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        super(ScrollableTkAggX, self).__init__(figure, master=self.fig_wrapper, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tkagg = self.get_tk_widget()
        self.tkagg.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)

        self.hbar = Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)

        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.hbar.set, scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))

        # when all widgets are in canvas
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.on_configure)
        # --- put frame in canvas ---
        self.canvas_frame = self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.fig_wrapper, anchor=tk.NW)

        ScrollableTkAggX_meths = vars(ScrollableTkAggX).keys()
        methods = vars(Pack).keys() | vars(Grid).keys() | vars(Place).keys()
        methods = methods.difference(ScrollableTkAggX_meths)

        for m in methods:
            if m[0] != '_' and m != 'config' and m != 'configure':
                setattr(self, m, getattr(self.canvas, m))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.canvas)

        # expand canvas_frame when canvas changes its size

    def on_configure(self, event):
        # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'

        self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(tk.ALL))
        # when all widgets are in canvas
        canvas_height = event.height
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.canvas_frame, height=canvas_height - 20)


class mclass:
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.figY = Figure(figsize=(10, 30))
        self.axesY = self.figY.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=10)

        self.figX = Figure(figsize=(30, 10))
        self.axesX = self.figX.subplots(ncols=10, nrows=3)

        self.canvasY = ScrollableTkAggY(figure=self.figY, master=window)
        self.canvasY.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.canvasY.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvasY.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.canvasX = ScrollableTkAggX(figure=self.figX, master=window)
        self.canvasX.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.canvasX.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvasX.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (800, 600))
        window.focus_set()

        self.do_plot()

    def do_plot(self):
        # Color used in mpl online documentation.
        mpl_grey_rvb = (51. / 255., 51. / 255., 51. / 255.)
        self.figY.suptitle("Matplotlib's math rendering engine ScrollableTkAggY",
                           color=mpl_grey_rvb, fontsize=14, weight='bold')

        self.figX.suptitle("Matplotlib's math rendering engine ScrollableTkAggX",
                           color=mpl_grey_rvb, fontsize=14, weight='bold')

        # Plotting features demonstration formulae

        for i in range(self.axesY.shape[0]):
            for j in range(self.axesY.shape[1]):
                self.axesY[i, j].set_xlabel("xlabel")
                self.axesY[i, j].set_ylabel("ylabel")
        self.figY.tight_layout()
        self.canvasY.draw()

        for i in range(self.axesX.shape[0]):
            for j in range(self.axesX.shape[1]):
                self.axesX[i, j].set_xlabel("xlabel")
                self.axesX[i, j].set_ylabel("ylabel")
        self.figX.tight_layout()
        self.canvasX.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    start = mclass(window)
    window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    # window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    window.mainloop()
```

and this the result.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06kq3.png)